# Flickr API Function Issue

Tags: python, api, flickr

I am having issues with my below API request to Flickr. My function takes as input a list of 10 photo ids. However when I print the data from my function I am only getting information based on 1 photo ID. Looking at my below function any ideas on what may be causing the contents of only 1 photo ID to print? Any help would be great.

```
for item in get_flickr_data(word)["photos"]["photo"]:
    photo_ids =item["id"].encode('utf-8')
    lst_photo_ids.append(photo_ids)

print lst_photo_ids 

lst_photo_ids = ['34117701526', '33347528313', '34158745075', '33315997274', '33315996984', '34028007021', '33315995844', '33347512113', '33315784134', '34024299271']

def get_photo_data(lst_photo_ids):
        baseurl = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/"
        params_d = {}
        params_d["method"] = "flickr.photos.getInfo"
        params_d["format"] = "json"
        params_d["photo_id"] = photo_ids
        params_d["api_key"] = FLICKR_KEY
        unique_identifier = params_unique_combination(baseurl,params_d)
        if unique_identifier in CACHE_DICTION:
            flickr_data_diction = CACHE_DICTION[unique_identifier]
        else:
            resp = requests.get(baseurl,params_d)
            json_result_text = resp.text[14:-1]
            flickr_data_diction = json.loads(json_result_text)
            CACHE_DICTION[unique_identifier] = flickr_data_diction
            fileref = open(CACHE_FNAME,"w")
            fileref.write(json.dumps(CACHE_DICTION))
            fileref.close()
        return flickr_data_diction
print get_photo_data(photo_ids)
```

Comment: Sort out your variable names... You have `lst_photo_ids` in the global scope, then you pass the nonexistant `photo_ids` to the function, which puts it into the `lst_photo_ids` parameter... and then you use the global variable `photo_ids` in the function.

Comment: @Rawing thanks for the feedback photo_ids exists in my prior code, I made an edit to show it in my original post.